# Icon visibility in the bottom bar

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement the item selection behavior such that when the user presses a button on the appbar the listview selection mode changes from none to multiple.

```
ListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
```

and the bottom bar changes the icon to Accept or Cancel multiple selected items.

```
AppBar SelectionAppBar = new AppBar();
        AppBarButton Acceptbutton = new AppBarButton { Label = "Accept", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Accept) };
        AppBarButton Cancelbutton = new AppBarButton { Label = "Cancel", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel) };
```

I would like the bottom bar icons to be visible when the selection mode changes to multiple, but change color (or brightness) only when the user actually selects any item in the list. Currently, the icon has same color whether or not any item is selected after enabling multiple selection mode.

Appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: Have you tried setting `IsEnabled=false` in respective AppBarButtons? That should do the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped. I have also put it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsEnabled` property of `AppBarButton` to enable/disable the buttons. Initially set `IsEnabled = false` for both buttons, then modify `IsEnabled` afterwards as user changes selection.